# macOS Sierra mysteriously capturing keyboard shortcuts involving Cmd-Ctrl-Alt

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I recently noticed that certain keyboard combinations involving Cmd+Ctrl+Alt (Cmd+Ctrl+Opt) are captured by my Mac but cannot figure out what is doing the capturing. For example, Cmd+Ctrl+Alt+j/; both trigger their pressed keys on the virtual keyboard showing that they are not being caught. However, Cmd+Ctrl+Alt+k/l show the modifiers being held but neither k or l are shown as triggered. Of the letter keys on my keyboard here are the ones that do not work with Cmd+Ctrl+Alt: t, p, a, s, k, l, c, m, ,, .

The above failures occur when I have no apps running besides Finder so there shouldn't be any app specific keyboard shortcut conflicts. I have looked through and disabled every possible keyboard shortcut in the Keyboard pane of System Preferences. As far as I’m aware there should be no conflicting shortcuts yet there certainly seems to be something capturing these combinations.

So I guess 2 questions:

1. Can someone confirm that they can in fact trigger these combinations on their Mac? For reference I’m on macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.6
2. Does anyone know either what might be capturing these shortcuts or how I might go about figuring that out?

Thanks in advance and this is my first time asking a question so please let me know if there’s other information that I should add here!

Comment: did you delete your other post?

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't, should I?

Comment: duplicate posts are not good - either delete it or mention you have it posted in both places on both...